# Compute the maximum-coverage path in an Occupancy Grid

Tags: java, grid, graph-theory, robotics

I am implementing a basic robot which uses a SLAM algorithm to produce an occupancy grid of it's environment. It is very simple with no probabilistic aspect, simply an enum to represent Empty, Occupied, Unexplored, Unreachable etc.

I was wondering if there is a well known algorithm to find the shortest path necessary to visit all of the grid cells once (it's a **Vacuum cleaner!**). Is this the Travelling Salesman Problem?

I have researched a couple of solutions based on Graphs, for example finding Hamiltonian Cycles, but i wondered if there was anything which efficiently worked on Grids directly.

The grid will be around 250x250 cells.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Not quite travelling salesman. Do you mind if you visit the same grid cell twice? Do you need to finish at the same point as you start at?

Comment: https://parasol.tamu.edu/~amato/Courses/620/openProblems/csce620-openProblem-P54_TSPinSolidGridGraphs_OzgurGonen.pdf Might help?

Comment: I don't mind visiting the same cell twice, just as long as this effect is minimized so the coverage is efficient! I'll take a look at that link too, thanks.

Comment: Do you still work on this concept? I'm interested in some know-how exchange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thought id add my solution to this unanswered question - Most algorithms I tried out were just too computationally complex. I settled on an approximation of the maximum-coverage path which was quite efficiently computed using the **reverse wavefront algorithm**.

Using this algorithm I was able to construct a maximum-coverage path of a 250x250 array of grid cells in around 5 seconds, which was certainly acceptable in my scenario.